# Keeping Rotation of one Axis and aligning others to Parent

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have a problem keeping one axis locked. I have two tools I can use to grab this mock-up needle like object.

[image: Tool grabbing "needle"]

I just need to be able to keep its rotation around itself (local y) and align the rest with the tool's rotation. Currently, however, I can only figure out how to rotate all the axes like so:

[image: Tool having grabbed "needle"]

The code just looks like this:

```
 case 1:
 this.transform.rotation = leftParent.transform.rotation;
 this.transform.SetParent (leftParent);
 break;
 case 2:
 this.transform.rotation = rightParent.transform.rotation;
 this.transform.SetParent (rightParent);
 break;
```

What i have tried:

- Using .Set on both local and global rotation, keeping the y and/or the w rotation
- = new Quaternion as local and global rotation, keeping the y and/or the w
- Rotating the needle after matching the parent rotation
- Rotating the needle after parenting it

Please let me know if there's something obvious I have missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is **Transform.localRotation** or **Tranform.localEulerAngles** : you can find more about those [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html).

In your case I'll do something like this (considering your "hand" object geometry is as expected) :

```
case1 :
//Adjust the rotation you want to keep here (I assume on Y axis in your case)
transform.SetParent(leftParent);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
break;
case2 :
//Adjust the rotation you want to keep here (I assume on Y axis in your case)
transform.SetParent(rightParent);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
break;
```

By the way, the `this` keyword is not needed in your situation since `transform` alone refers to the **Transform** at which the script is attached.